# How do i simulate a click event in a webbrowser control? .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webbrowser-control

So there is a button call next (page). Its href link is site/blah/#. So i know its really running javascript code. After i finish parsing the first page i would like to parse the next page. How do i simulate a mouse click there so i can continue loading and parsing pages?

i am using C# .NET

Answer (score 5, accepted):

childElement.RaiseEvent("OnClick");

Answer (score 4):

If you know the id of the  tag you can use below given code

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("submit").InvokeMember("click")
```

if you dont know the id you can follow this code

```
foreach (System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement html in WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")) {
    if (html.InnerText == "YOUR TEXT") {
         html.InvokeMember("click");
    }
}
```

Contact if you have any doubt

Comment: What is the difference between  this answer and user34537's ?