# Reading the content of WebBrowser control

Tags: .net, vb.net, browser

I have made a HttpWebRequest to a page to get the page containing a table that I want to parse, But the problem is that there are some JavaScripts that needs to run before being able to access the table. So Now I want to have a WebBrowser control and let the page load in the webbrowser and then read the html content of it to be parsed! Any heads up how I can do this?

Also when I load the page in WebBrowser control it gives me some javascript error, and once I pass all those errors it will loads the full page. Is there anyway to bypass those errors ?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could set `ScriptErrorsSuppressed` to true. This suppresses all dialogs displayed by WebBrowser control. In case where you want to selectively ignore errors you would have to subscribe to `Window.Error` event on the document. For more details check [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.scripterrorssuppressed.aspx)

Alternatively you could use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com).  in which case you wouldn't have to use WebBrowser control at all.

Example:

```
    HtmlDocument htmlDocument = null;
    HtmlWeb htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
    htmlWeb.PreHandleDocument = new HtmlWeb.PreHandleDocumentHandler((document) => htmlDocument = document );
    htmlWeb.Load(url, "GET");

    foreach (HtmlNode item in htmlDocument.DocumentNode)
    {
        // find your table node
    }
```

Comment: Hey thank you, I haven't tried this but on this post I showed what I have done, Can you have a look at it and tell me if that is possible with your method ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491170/unexpected-behaviour-while-using-httpwebrequest-on-a-form-to-obtain-a-table-for

Comment: Problem is that some javascripts are preventing the table to load when I do httpwebrequest